Brother TD-4420DN Ubuntu 22.04 installed - but not printing
When i want to print a label or anything like a testpage from the printer's app in ubuntu - it shows completed, but the printer does not print anything.
I have installed the Driver from Brother's Homepage and added the Printer via the localhost:631 CUPS webinterface choosin the .ppd provided alongside with the driver. The Printer has a static address and can be pinged, the webinterface works.
I have tried also the .deb package from Brother's homepage, but it seems to install the printer in USB only not even asking for network installation option.
When i want to print network settings by holding the printer's button - it works, no paper jam no nothing - so i don't see any"physical" obstacle.
/var/log/cups/error_log does not give any error either...
Do you have have any ideas? Help would be really appreciated!
EDIT:
Static IP assignment
The static IP has been set via the printer's web interface, then the printer has been added, before i have added it by the one assigned with DHCP - it made no difference, but i keep the static IP for reasons of network order.
gLabels
I am using it regularly, printing via it gave the same result as test page from "printers" menu, or CUPS or lp -d...

Have you tried adding the printer (without interference from adding drivers) from Settings > Printers and what was the result? As for printing labels have a look at gLabels from Ubuntu Software. I use this utility on 22.04 (and have on previous versions too) to very good effect.

"The Printer has a static address" please [edit] you question with detail on how that was achieved eg in the printer itself and/or your router and how was the IP Address chosen? Randomly or to some plan?

@graham thx, i have edited the post above responding to your suggestions

Try the  LPD protocol in CUPS and in the printer.  It may work without all the bells and whistles like ink level, etc.

In the End... it was the Media Size that prevented the printer from printing.
I have followed these steps:

Install Driver from Brother Homepage

Add Printer through Ubuntu "Printers" Menu -> Add Printer

Contrary to adding the printer via CUPS webinterface - i can now choose the Media Size in the page setup:



Here you see missing media size option in the automatic added printer:


After choosing the 102mm for the labels i had inserted into the printer - it works.

I thank you all for trying to help out and for your effort & input!
